# How can I enable decorators support when running tests with CRA 2.1?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

I am trying to get the tests of a React application that uses decorators and Typescript to work with Create React App v2.1.0

I am aware that decorators are not officially supported.

I can run the application fine thanks to [React App Rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) and [@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators).

Where I am stuck is to enable decorator support when running the tests.

My npm `test` script is : `"test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom --runInBand"`

Tests fails with:

> The 'decorators' plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option,
>   whose value must be a boolean. If you are migrating from Babylon/Babel
>   6 or want to use the old decorators proposal, you should use the
>   'decorators-legacy' plugin instead of 'decorators

I have tried to add a *.babelrc* file with the following :

```
{
  "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]]
}
```

but get hit by:

> Cannot use the decorators and decorators-legacy plugin together

Comment: in babelrc add these:
`[ "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true } ],
    [ "transform-class-properties", {
      "loose": true
    }]`

and install transform-class-properties that will allow you to use decorators

Comment: @somsgod This results in the same error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a Create React App maintainer.

Decorators are supported if you're using TypeScript and work with tests, no extra configuration required (CRA `^2.1.1`, there was a bug in `2.1.0`).

Decorators are **only unsupported in JavaScript**.

---

First, remove `react-app-rewired` and switch your scripts back to `react-scripts`.
Next, remove your `.babelrc` file.

Finally, convert any files using decorators to be TypeScript files (`.tsx`). Everything should just work now!

Also, your test script should only read `"test": "react-scripts test"` or `"test": "react-scripts test --runInBand"`. Passing `--env=jsdom` is unnecessary as specified in the 2.0 upgrade guide.

Comment: Tests are much slower (5 to 10 times) to run since v2 and don't seem [to be the only one](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4453) but that's an issue for another day.

Comment: We are aware tests are slower and are working hard to fix it -- it's mostly affecting Windows users.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5304

Answer (score 0):

@Onlyann take a backup of you current package.json or project.

And try this configuration, it should help you and you can add extra packages afterwards.

```
// package.json 
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "^7.0.0-beta.42", 

// .babelrc 
   {
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": false }],
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-stage-2"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
    ],
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Nope. One of the keys in this question is that it uses Create React App. Have you tried your suggested solution ?

Comment: I dont use create react app. I have setuped manually React + Webpack + Babel + Mobx.
Can you share your package.json and babel contents will try on myside to resolve your issue.

Comment: Without ejecting, you currently cannot make cra v2 use a custom babel configuration. I hope this will change at some point.